# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45451: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, datastax

I am a newbie to Kubernetes and trying to set up a cluster that runs Cassandra in my local machine. I have used kind to create a cluster that was successful. After that when I try to run *`kubectl cluster-info`*, I am getting the below error:

*`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45451: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`*

On *`docker container ls`*, I could see the control-plane running on the container using the port as below:

```sh
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                       NAMES
1c4b6101b8ff        kindest/node:v1.18.2   "/usr/local/bin/entr"   3 hours ago         Up 2 hours          127.0.0.1:45451->6443/tcp   kind-cassandra-control-plane
625fee22e0e6        kindest/node:v1.18.2   "/usr/local/bin/entr"   3 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                      kind-cassandra-worker
```

Am able to view the config file by executing *`kubectl config view`* as below, which confirms the kubectl is able to read the correct config file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://127.0.0.1:45451
  name: kind-kind-cassandra
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kind-kind-cassandra
    user: kind-kind-cassandra
  name: kind-kind-cassandra
current-context: kind-kind-cassandra
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kind-kind-cassandra
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

**UPDATE:**

When I run *`netstat`*, I could see below as the active connections on 127.0.0.1

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:2869
 TCP    127.0.0.1:5354
 TCP    127.0.0.1:5354
 TCP    127.0.0.1:27015
 TCP    127.0.0.1:49157
 TCP    127.0.0.1:49158
 TCP    127.0.0.1:49174
```

Any help is really appreciated. TIA

Comment: What is it running on that port 45451.  Ideally it should be Kube-api server target:port defined in the server section of your kubeconfig...Could you confirm kube-apiserver port?

Comment: Rohit, thanks for getting back. As I had posted above in the 'docker container ls', the control-plane is running inside a docker container on the port 45451. Is that what you're referring to? If not, how do I get the kube-apiserver port when am not able to connect to the cluster ?

Comment: Added an update if that could help

Comment: What's your OS? @Prince

Comment: . OS: Win 7 Docker ver: Docker for Windows v 19.03.1 installed using DockerToolbox-19.03.1 @HelloWorld

Answer (score 6):

Try using this command

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

Comment: please add more description

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect it to be possibly a `kind` issue, not `kubernetes` issue so I'd investigate this first. Please show the following:

- Operating System
- Docker Version and release ("docker for mac", "docker for windows" etc)
- How exactly kind cluster was created, config file etc.
- `kind get nodes`
- Resources

  - Given Windows or Mac, how many resources allocated for docker
  - Given Linux, how many resources the machine has

Afterwards, I suggest to recreate the `kind` cluster.

Comment: Below are the details.

**OS**: Win 7
**Docker ver**: Docker for Windows v 19.03.1 installed using DockerToolbox-19.03.1.
Cluster was created using the commands as given in week5-Cass-in-k8s. Contents of the config as posted above.
On running `kind get nodes`, I get the message 'No kind nodes found for cluster "kind".'
I have created the cluster with only one worker node, the details of which is also posted above. The base memory of the system in VMBox in at 1024MB. 
I had also tried creating the cluster multiple times after removing the images/container, but no success.

Comment: Also, `kind get nodes --name "kind-cassandra"` returns  kind-cassandra-control-plane, 
kind-cassandra-worker

Comment: Try to increase memory and cpu for the docker virtual machine please. Then remove this cluster and start a new one.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response @Hades Architect. I tried providing the maximum to the VM, still am getting the error. Not sure if there are any proxy settings that I need to update to enable the connection (though I have provided NO_PROXY for Docker Host: 192.168.99.100).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Windows 10 with Hyper-V and `minikube start --driver=docker` was not enough. I had to:

- uninstall minikube
- remove **.minikube** folder from my user profile
- reinstall minikube